# Is orElseThrow better than if(obj == null)?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, null, option-type

I've got a question.

Is this

```
Issue issue = Optional.ofNullable(someMethod())
    .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Issue is null"));
```

better than this

```
Issue issue = someMethod();
if (issue == null) {
    throw new Exception("Issue is null");
}
```

?

Comment: Not really. If you're using the optional for something else, 1 might be more convenient. But as you have it here, the `if` statement is clearer.

Comment: The main idea of `orElseThrow()` is that you can continue the method cascade afterwards. So you can write `a.orElseThrow().nextMethod().anotherMethod()` because the method returns the object inside the `Optional`. In your example I would find the second version easier to read. But if you plan to continue the cascade, the first might be better.

Comment: There is a [nice talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14) by the devs on `Optional` and its usage and misusage. It covers the idea behind this method too.

Comment: Well, you've saved 2 curly brackets and 1 semicolon in the first example. Although, 2nd one is clearer and easier to read. Choice is yours.

Comment: `Optional` is for return values from methods. So `Optional.ofNullable()` might go *into* `someMethod` so it could return an `Optional`. As the code stands, there’s no point in using an `Optional`. As a detail, I’d throw a `NullPointerException`, not just an `Exception`.

Comment: Throwing the unspecific exception type `Exception` is discouraged, regardless of how you do it. If `issue` is `null`, there is no reason to use something other than `NullPointerException`, which already speaks for itself. Use [`Objects.requireNonNull(issue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-), resp. [`Objects.requireNonNull(issue, "Issue is null")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-)… You may even inline it: `Issue issue = Objects.requireNonNull(someMethod(), "Issue is null");`

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `Optional` is not to replace every single null reference in your codebase but rather to help design better APIs in which—just by reading the signature of a method—users can tell whether to expect an optional value. In addition, Optional forces you to actively unwrap an Optional to deal with the absence of a value; as a result, you protect your code against unintended null pointer exceptions.

[Optional reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

As per [doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) Optional should use where multi chaining call done and not sure which one will throw the `NullPointerException`.
you must consider to read doc sure it will  help you to understand `Optional` usage.